# Python D&D randomizer Question with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am wondering about a custom D&D Character Randomizer I am working on in Tkinter.

The whole idea is to use Tkinters checkboxes to be able to select the classes and races you do and dont want!

However ive run into a hiccup:

There is 13 classes, and 21 races. The way ive figured out to make the checkboxes be selected is to get the selected boxes to append the selected class / race to a list, then randomly select from the list!

```
if barbarianVar.get() == 1:
        classes.append('Barbarian')
```

However, there is 13 classes and 21 races so I am wondering if i can use for loops, and if so, how i would go about doing so

Thank you for any and all info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be able to do so using `random`. Using `random.choice(array)` we can get a random element from the array.

Assuming `barbarianVar.get()` is checking whether the barbarian checkbox is checked, the following should work:

```
import random

classes = []

if barbarianVar.get() == 1:
    classes.append('Barbarian')
if wizardVar.get() == 1:
    classes.append('Wizard')
if paladinVar.get() == 1:
    classes.append('Paladin')
        
print("I have randomly generated " + random.choice(classes) + " as your class")
```

Now if we wish to incorporate a for loop into this, we could do so if we have an array full of each of the classes and another array full of each of the class names:

```
import random

class_variable = [barbarianVar, wizardVar, paladinVar]
class_name = ["Barbarian", "Wizard", "Paladin"]
class_possible = []

for i in range(len(class_variable)):
    if (class_variable[i].get() == 1):
        class_possible.append(class_name[i])

print("I have randomly generated " + random.choice(class_possible) + " as your class")
```

Repeat the if statements for each of the classes and reuse the same logic for races.

Comment: Thank you!

However i was just wondering if i could get away with for loops, since thats gonna be a lot of if statements to do

Comment: @FritzPappo I see. I didn't realize you meant use a for loop to go through each of the inputs. I'll update my answer accordingly. My bad